# How to open new JFrame by clicking on button in other JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I write project in Java in NetBeans. I created a new project and didn't check to create main class, because I create all with drag and drop, make some buttons and events on them. Then, I created two `JFrame` classes: `NewJFrame` and `NewJFrame1`, in `NewJFrame` I a have a button in both frames.

So, can you tell me how can I make event to open first frame by clicking on button in second frame, and to open second frame by clicking on button in first frame?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: In NewJFrame.java button event call NewJFrame1 jFrame1 = new  NewJFrame1(); and do opposite in NewJFrame1.java button event.

Comment: *"I created a new project and didn't check to create main class, because I create all with drag and drop"*  That makes no sense to me.  A D'n'D GUI might have a main method, and it may not.  Likewise a 'hand made' GUI might have a main method or may not.

Comment: Thanks to all... This is solution..

NewJFrame1 jFrame1 = new NewJFrame1();
        jFrame1.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0):

```
//Make constructor class for both JFrame then 
//write this code into your JFrame where your button is accesing another JFrame
//Note:- jb=button var name,
//       jf=JFrame vatr name,
//       addnew()=JFrame Class to be open.

 jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new addnew();
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        } 
    });
```